# OpenAPI cannot find schema for array element

Tags: java, arrays, openapi

I am currently working on the project using OpenAPI v.3.1 library.
I do need to validate a request against the Schema in the OpenAPI object created from the swagger YAML file.
Everything is OK, except one thing. If the type of the property equal to "array" like in the following snippet:

```
            "responseAttrList": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "responseAttrList": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "description": "Provide One or more Group Names to see the Valid response attributes",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I cannot get the schema element for the array items.
javadoc https://javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models/latest/io/swagger/v3/oas/models/media/Schema.html does not provide any clues in this regard.
Is it a bug in the OpenAPI, or I am missing something?
Any clues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you do mean by "cannot get the schema element for the array items"? What is your workflow exactly and what tool/library do you use that doesn't give the expected result?

Comment: If your question is about Java annotations, you need [`@ArraySchema`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models/latest/io/swagger/v3/oas/models/media/ArraySchema.html), here's an example: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#arrayschema